# Historical Record of Moderation Policy Changes?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a list of changes to moderation policies published anywhere? It would be nice to see something like:

- 1/1/2014 - Questions requesting lists of resources are now permitted [justification]
- 1/1/2013 - etc

Comment: No such list exists, but in my experience policy changes gradually so there wouldn't be a fixed date that you could identify

Comment: see [Recent feature changes...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/165773) and [Mod Newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @psubsee2003 are you sure that no employee doesn't have such a list?

Comment: @lostsock there may be something general.... but my point still stands... moderation changes are generally community driven and not just decisions that were made on a specific date by a specific individual.  So any changes would be mostly gradual and cannot be fixed to a specific date.  There may be some exceptions driven by the SE Community team but they would be more about asking moderators to handle specific cases differently.